How might fog rapidly be created during space warfare?
Context
In my setting, ships have deflecting shields that are essentially fields of sonic frequencies. Sounds are used to penetrate these shields - a mosquito tone on an assassin, or broadside thunder cannons to disrupt the shield without destroying the precious ship within. Capture of a ship is preferred over it's destruction.
Secondly, outer space is breathable, has weather etc.
The two main weapon types between ships in space are these thunder cannons (imagine a Fus Ro Dah from Skyrim as a cannon for shield disruption) and laser guided lightning strikes.
Prompt
How could you explain these clashes between ships rapidly manifesting fog or stormclouds around the ships locked in battle?
Thoughts:
Maybe theres some temperature differences between the inside and outside of the ship's field? Gasses and vapors can pass through, but maybe temperature control on the ships for comfort's sake. Could this explain some rapid condensation interaction with lightning? Just one idea.

It's a deliberate defense Lasers can't penetrate the opaque fog, and lightning bolts will be dissipated by electrically conductive fog. Your own weapons and telescopes need to be long enough to poke out of your own fogbank, but the rest of the ship is safely hidden behind it.

Smoke screens are a real thing. Late 19th to mid-20th century naval ships were very good at laying smoke screens at a moment's notice.

For future reference, providing your own answers ("Thoughts") and asking for more is prohibited. Please review the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] (where you'll find this prohibition) and [ask]. Thanks.

Also, can you clarify a few things? (a) When you say fog, do you really mean a field of water droplets? Or as @AlexP suggests, is a smoke screen sufficient? (b) What's the purpose behind this? Is it only an aesthetic of the battles or is it being used for a reason? (c) Do you need this in 2D or 3D? Yes, in real life fog has thickness, but it's usually very thin compared to the land it covers. And finally, (d) Your space has substance and weather, do you expect the solution to hold up against wind?

It does not need to hold up against wind! I'm mostly looking for a source of suspense, tension, and drama - a literal fog of war amidst the battle. It would need to be in 3D, I want to see a bunch of large ships disappearing in stormclouds/fog etc of battle. Its a very solarpunk/natural science world, so I want something naturally coded that kind of matches the smoke and dust of cannonfire and such.

I also want it to be a natural byproduct of the fights, not necessarily a designed effect. Naturally, people would plan for it, utilize it, etc. but this is intended to be separate from smoke screens and such.

Pressure Waves and Water vapor!
You say you have shields that work on Sound. Sound is a Pressure wave. You also say that in your outerspace there is Weather - which means there must be Moisture in the air...
Vapor Cones on Aircraft

As soon as your Shields are turned on, the Pressure Waves will induce an area of low pressure (just like the top of an Aircrafts wing in the above picture) - this will cause any moisture to crystalize into a cloud or...
FOG!

Especially as those shields get disrupted and reinitialize, etc. that could create those over and over! This is just what I was looking for for my purposes!

Have a battle
It is easy to over think sometimes. If we look at real world we see dust everywhere. Some we can see as things are fired or launched when dust is kicked up by the force. Others are from impact, where anything from simple bullets and the surface they hit partially disintegrating, to explosive and gas expanding from explosions and whatnot. The advantage of creating smoke or mist is that you need relatively little to create thick clouds. It is why in general you can physically move easily through any cloud if we ignore our health. Smoke grenades are a great way to demonstrate this. In such a small package is an amount of thick smoke that can blanket a large space.
Create your own volcanic lightning
I still want to delve into the ability to harness it fir offence. It seems you are set on lightning from the fog, similar to rainclouds. I would offer a different solution. Go look at pictures and videos of volcanic lightning. There is very little moisture in the air, yet the particles can create an difference in charged particles that can lead to lightning strikes. Your spaceships could utilise this. They create thick smoke like a volcano, though via science they figured out the optimal particle type, heat and density to create lightning. This is then directed at the enemy. How to direct it might be out of scope, I'll still suggest something like harpoons with exposed electrical wires.
This way you can have the hard core looking volcanic lightning harnessed in ship to ship battle. There's obviously better ways to attack, but the rule of cool allows it.

Check out comets and artificial comets.
In 1959 Luna 1 vaporized 1 kg of sodium. That created a giant and very bright cloud that could be barely seen from Earth with naked eye from 120,000 km for several minutes.
Calculation show that lithium is 40 times more effective than sodium.

You could use some kind of explosive to create a cloud in a short time. I’m not sure how that works in space but I assume it’s similar seeing as stars explode and produce gas clouds. I’m sure if a gas cloud were thick enough it might be a good defence
